# How can a persistent entity have an associated identifier but no representation in the database?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entity, persistent

I was reading Hibernate user guide when I came across the definition of a managed/persistent entity. It [says](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc):

> `managed`, or `persistent`
>
> the entity has an associated identifier and is associated with a persistence context. It may or may not physically exist in the database yet.

I read somewhere else (some forum on the internet) that the difference between a detached entity and an transient is that a detached entity has an identifier associated with it which it gets from the database store when we make a representation of the entity. So if that is the case how can an entity have an associated identifier but no representation in the database if it has to first have a representation to get the identifier? Sorry if my question is not clear enough I will elaborate if you ask.

Comment: The section of the guide you link also documents what a `transient` and `detatched` entity is. The `transient` description says: "_It has no persistent representation in the database and typically no identifier value has been assigned (unless the assigned generator was used)_".

Comment: An entity can have an id at the class level but no id at database level. it says "associated" identifier. the emphasis here is on the word association which I assumed it means the database level.

Comment: A transient entity is still transient even though we assign an id annotation to one of its properties. the annotation makes no difference otherwise it would mean transient = detached. that means a managed/persistent entity with no id association in the database is a also a transient?

Comment: An entity that has an associated identifier doesn't need to be represented in the database to get the associated identifier, think identifiers generated from sequences ...